# How to check for an empty XML element in JAVA

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have an XML as follows:

```
<info>
    <userId>Admin</userId>
    <userNotes></userNotes>         
</info>
```

I am trying to parse this in JAVA. and here is my code snippet:

```
NodeList userIdNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("userId");

if (userIdNodeList!=null) {
    userId = userIdNodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue().trim();
}            

NodeList userNotesNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("userNotes");

if (userNotesNodeList!=null) {
    userNotes = userNotesNodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue().trim();
}
```

But the above code is throwing a NULL pointer error because the `userNotes` element is empty.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You're calling trim on a null value returned by getNodeValue. Check the result of that method before calling trim.

Answer (score 9):

*(Corrected)*

`userNotesNodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().getLength()` will return 0 if there are no child elements nor text.

**Why**

`userNotesNodeList` is the list of `<userNotes>` nodes. There are 1. Anyway you could check the length to verify it.

`userNotesNodeList.item(0)` is the first `<userNotes>` element.

`userNotesNodeList.item(0).getChildNodes()` is the list of things that are inside `<userNotes>...</userNotes>`.

In case of no text this is a NodeList with 0 elements so

```
userNotesNodeList.item(0).getChildNodes().getLength() should return 0.
```

I suggest using vars for intermidiate results (to make a clearer code). Or creating some helper methods to avoid this cumbersome XML api.

```
NodeList userNotesNodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("userNotes");
// userNotesNodeList should not be null, it can be zero length, but not null
Element userNotesElement = (Element) userNotesNodeList.item(0);
if (userNotesElement.getChildNodes().getLength() > 0) // then it has text
{
   userNotes = userNotesElement.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
}
```